# Unable to use azure custom vision python SDK predictor.detect_image function

Tags: python, azure, microsoft-custom-vision, azure-python-sdk

I followed the code mentioned in below link
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-quickstart-code/blob/master/python/CustomVision/ObjectDetection/CustomVisionQuickstart.py

Able to upload images, train model, publish model into customvision.api
But when I tried executing the line predictor.detect_image, I am getting below error as
CustomVisionErrorException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'Unauthorized'. Please help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> But when I tried executing the line predictor.detect_image, I am getting below error as CustomVisionErrorException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'Unauthorized'.

As you haven't provided code to repro the issue, to resolve **unauthorized** error, based on the available solutions, you can try the following ways:

According to [areddish](https://github.com/microsoft/Cognitive-CustomVision-Windows/issues/16)  and [shawnmittal](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-quickstart-code/issues/295), make sure to provide correct **prediction credentials and endpoint**.

- Check for trained iteration
- In the project's performance tab, make that trained iteration as default.

```
TRAINING_ENDPOINT = "TRAINING_RESOURCE_ENDPOINT"
training_key = "TRAINING_RESOURCE_API_KEY"
PREDICTION_ENDPOINT = "PREDICTION_RESOURCE_ENDPOINT"
prediction_key = "PREDICTION_API_KEY"
prediction_resource_id = "PREDICTION_RESOURCE_ID"

credentials = ApiKeyCredentials(in_headers={"Training-key": training_key})
trainer = CustomVisionTrainingClient(TRAINING_ENDPOINT, credentials)
prediction_credentials = ApiKeyCredentials(in_headers={"Prediction-key": prediction_key})
predictor = CustomVisionPredictionClient(PREDICTION_ENDPOINT, prediction_credentials)
```

You can refer to [Operation returned an invalid status code 'unauthorized' on azure cognitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67399647/operation-returned-an-invalid-status-code-unauthorized-on-azure-cognitive)

Comment: Hi @DeepDate-MT, thanks for the info. After running it for 4 times, it started giving expected results on 4th time.  Thanks for offering help!